# Is there a more formal term or name for a dictionary of lists?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, computer-science, terminology, multimap

For documentation purposes, I'm looking for a canonical or standard name for this simple data structure. It seems like there should be one, but Google and my memory are failing me.

Here's an example in JSON-style notation:

```
 {
     drummers: ['Ringo Starr', 'Danny Carey', 'Keith Moon'],
     singers: ['Chris Cornell', 'Peter Gabriel'],
     guitarists: ['Stevie Ray Vaughan', 'Slash'],
     cowbell_players: [],
     bassists: ['Flea']
 }
```

Comment: @Dwight: Those are independent of the type of the mapped to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap), perhaps?

> A multimap (sometimes also multihash) is a generalization of a map or associative array abstract data type in which more than one value may be associated with and returned for a given key. <sup><sub>(snip)</sub></sup> Often the multimap is implemented as a map with lists or sets as the map values.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say so. You beat me to it.

Comment: That's it. It's been so long since I've used C++ that I couldn't dredge it up from memory -- I kept thinking of "multiset."

Answer (score 0):

In general, it it is a map, mapping a key to a list. Dictionary is appropiate as well, Hashtable wouldn't be as Hashtable connotates an implementation.